# I am using imfilter to blur an image but it is showing error

Tags: image, kernel

```
A=imread('cameraman.tif');

h =fspecial('gaussian',size(A),1.0); 

g =imfilter(A,h);
```

The above code is throwing an error

```
" FSPECIAL: size(N) should be less than or equal 2."
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: Could it be that A > 2?  Double-check the result of `SIZE(A)`.

Comment: size(A) result is ans =

    [90    90     4]

Comment: So... The size isn't 2.  There's your problem.  You would be best served starting there.

Comment: this means that fspecial function can take only 2D matrix?

Comment: and now the 3D matrix that is obtained from A is to be converted to 2D?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about your platform.  It's just that if the error is indicative of your input, you should consider checking your input.